# Multiple similar columns with similar values

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe looks like:

```
  name      education        education_2          education_3
name_1            NaN       some college                  NaN
name_2            NaN                NaN      graduate degree
name_3    high school                NaN                  NaN
```

I just want to keep one education column. I tried to use the conditional statement and compared to each other, I got nothing but error though. I also looked through the merge solution, but in vain. Does anyone know how to deal with it using Python or pandas? Thank you in advance.

```
  name            education
name_1         some college
name_2      graduate degree
name_3          high school
```

Comment: Is it one column will be filled(not nan) in a row and rest be nan?

Comment: @Kate, added a solution. works for you?

Comment: @Naveed - It works if I ignore other columns. The whole dataframe also includes other columns (e.g. age, income, etc.); how would I know that `bfill` uses educ2 and educ3 to fill in educ?

Comment: updated the solution,

Comment: See my answer for using `.filter()` to easily filter by column category. Since it appears your actual data is a bit more complicated~

Answer (score 2):

One day I hope they'll have better functions for `String` type rows, rather than the limited support for columns currently available:

```
df['education'] = (df.filter(like='education') # Filters to only Education columns.
                     .T                        # Transposes
                     .convert_dtypes()         # Converts to pandas dtypes, still somewhat in beta.
                     .max()                    # Gets the max value from the column, which will be the not-null one.
                  )
df = df[['name', 'education']]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     name        education
0  name 1     some college
1  name 2  graduate degree
2  name 3      high school
```

---

Looping this wouldn't be too hard e.g.:

```
cols = ['education', 'age', 'income']
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df.filter(like=col).bfill(axis=1)[col]

df = df[['name'] + cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

use bfill to fill the empty (NaN) values

```
df.bfill(axis=1).drop(columns=['education 2','education 3'])
```

```
    name    education
0   name 1  some college
1   name 2  graduate degree
2   name 3  high school
```

if there are other columns in between then choose the columns to apply bfill
In essence, if you have multiple columns for education that you need to consolidate under a single column then choose the columns to which you apply the bfill. subsequently, you can delete those columns from which you back filled.

```
df[['education','education 2','education 3']].bfill(axis=1).drop(columns=['education 2','education 3'])
```

Comment: See my answer for a way to not have so many hard-coded values~

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.fillna` to do so.

```
df['combine'] = df[['education','education2','education3']].fillna('').sum(axis=1)

df
    name     education    education2       education3          combine
0  name1          NaN  some college              NaN     some college
1  name2          NaN           NaN  graduate degree  graduate degree
2  name3  high school           NaN              NaN      high school
```

If you have a lot of columns to combine, you can try this.

```
df['combine'] = df[df.columns[1:]].fillna('').sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Or course, you can assign it to a new dataframe too :)